# Laravel verify email

Tags: laravel, email

Actually that is my second question with the same problem. Well.

I need the private function like this:

```php
if(email is verified){
Route::get('personal_cabinet', function () {
    return('hey you are a good person');
});
}
else{
Route::get('personal_cabinet', function () {
    return('pls verify your email address');
});
}
```

Someone can help me with that? I m a beginner in this framework

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: in app\User.php
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to correct the same code you wrote, this helps :

```
 Route::get('personal_cabinet', function () {
 if(email is verified)
      return('hey you are a good person');
   else
      return('pls verify your email address');
 });
```

But it's better to check verification in the controller, like this :

```
// Route file
Route::get('personal_cabinet', 'HomeController@pcabinet');

// HomeController.php
class HomeController extends Controller
{
  public function pcabinet()
  {
      if(emailver == 1)
         return('hey you are a good person');
      else
         return('pls verify your email address');

  }
 }
```